# Pygame sprite collision: object has no attribute 'sprites'

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

I am making a game in Python pygame and have made a moving background, a jumping sprite as a player and spawning obstacles. Now I am working on the collision between the player and obstacles and have worked out some code but eventually an error occurs:

```
      collided = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, obsticles, True)
    File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site 
packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1514, in spritecollide
        for s in group.sprites():
    AttributeError: 'Obsticles' object has no attribute 'sprites'
```

I have no idea, why that class is not a sprite and how to make it a sprite. I hope after fixing this error the collision works.

player image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLKvl.png)

obsticles image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNq5y.png)

background image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY5l7.png)

```
import pygame, random

pygame.init()


W, H = 800,600
HW, HH = W/2,H/2
AREA = W * H

bg = pygame.image.load('Linn.png')
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (800, 600))

DS = pygame.display.set_mode((W,L))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()



class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self, x, y, py, paat, veerg, rida):
        super(Player,self).__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.jumping = False
        self.platform_y = py
        self.velocity_index = 0

        self.paat = pygame.image.load('STlaev.png').convert_alpha()
        self.paat = pygame.transform.scale(self.paat,(64,64))
        self.rect = self.paat.get_rect()

        self.veerg = veerg
        self.rida = rida
        self.kokku = veerg * rida

        self.rect = self.paat.get_rect()
        W = self.veergL = self.rect.width/veerg
        H = self.weegK = self.rect.height/rida
        HW,HH = self.veergKeskel = (W/2,H/2)

        self.veerg = list([(index % veerg * W, int(index/veerg) * H,W,H )for index in range(self.kokku)])

        self.handle = list([ #pildi paigutamise voimalikud positsioonid
            (0, 0), (-HW, 0), (-W, 0),
            (0, -HH), (-HW, -HH), (-W, -HH),
            (0, -W), (-HW, -H), (-W, -H),])

        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.paat)

    def do_jumpt(self):
        global velocity
        if self.jumping:
            self.y += velocity[self.velocity_index]
            self.velocity_index += 1
            if self.velocity_index >= len(velocity) - 1:
                self.velocity_index = len(velocity) - 1
            if self.y > self.platform_y:
                self.y = self.platform_y
                self.jumping = False
                self.velocity_index = 0



    def draw(self, DS,veergindex,x,y,handle=0):
        DS.blit(self.paat,(self.x+self.handle[handle][0], self.y + self.handle[handle][1]),self.veerg[veergindex])


    def do(self):
        self.do_jumpt()
        p.draw(DS,index%p.kokku,300,300,0)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y



p = Player(310, 200, 200, 'STlaev.png', 4, 1) #Mangija algkordinaadid, huppe 
korgus, pilt, sprite valik
velocity = list([(i/ 2.0)-14 for i in range (0,50)])  #Huppe ulatus
index = 3

def keys(player):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_UP] and player.jumping == False:
       player.jumping = True




class Obsticles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, img, width, height):
        super(Obsticles,self).__init__()
        self.img = pygame.image.load('box.png').convert()
        self.img = pygame.transform.scale(self.img, (64,64))
        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.hitbox = (x,y,width,height)

        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

    def draw(self, DS):
        DS.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y



def redrawWindow():
    for i in objects:
        i.draw(DS)


pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+2, random.choice([2000, 3000, 1000, 4000,0]))
objects = []


'''Sprites'''
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player(310, 200, 200, 'STlaev.png', 4, 1)
obsticles = Obsticles(832,300,'box.png',64,64)

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player,obsticles)
ob = pygame.sprite.Group(obsticles)

x=0
while True:

    '''Game loop'''
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+2:
            r = random.randrange(0,2)
            if r == 0:
                objects.append(Obsticles(832,300,64,64))


    '''Obsticle speed and deleting'''
    for i in objects:
        i.x -= 5     #the speed of the obsticle
        if i.x < -64: #deleting obsticle from the window
            objects.pop(objects.index(i))

    '''Background movement'''
    back_x = x % bg.get_rect().width
    DS.blit(bg, (back_x - bg.get_rect().width, 0))
    if back_x < W:
        DS.blit(bg, (back_x, 0))
    x -= 1

    '''Sprites'''

    all_sprites.update()

    collided = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,obsticles ,True)
    for i in collided:
        print('Collision.')


    '''Fuctions'''
    keys(p)
    p.do()
    index+=1

    redrawWindow()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collided = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, obsticles, True)`

Its the fact you are using the object `obsticles`, not the sprite group `ob`. So to fix it you do this:

`collided = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, ob, True)`